# How to go stack traces from `polyc`?

Tags: polyml

I am using PolyML compiler 5.6 Release on Mac OS. I'm compiling and running some code which raises an exception (`Fail "undefined"`). I am expecting my compiled app to exit with a stack trace when the exception is raised; but instead it exits silently.

How can I get PolyML to show stack traces or at least line numbers where the exception is raised?

Comment: Have you seen this page? http://www.polyml.org/documentation/Tutorials/Debugging.html

Answer (score 1):

Running your application under the debugger is the best way to find out where the exception is happening.

If you can't or don't want to use the debugger you can get line number and source file information by adding a handler and using `PolyML.Exception.exceptionLocation` to get the location from the exception packet.  See http://polyml.org/documentation/Reference/PolyMLException.html

In Poly/ML 5.6 you can also use `PolyML.exception_trace` to get a trace of the calls that led to the exception but that's likely to be removed in the next release,